# How to highlight the span of a specific color area?

Tags: c#, aforge

I have a code that finds a specific color area

```
     private readonly Color _from20 = Color.FromArgb(254,254, 244);
     private readonly Color _to20 = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);//set color range

  for (int i = 0; i < windowOriginal.Width; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < windowOriginal.Height; j++)
   {
       Color c = imageOriginal.GetPixel(i, j);
      if (ColorWithinRange(c,  _from20, _to20))
     {

      Drawing.Line(objectsOriginal, new IntPoint((int)i, (int)j),new IntPoint((int)i, (int)j), Color.Red);//drawing
     
    }
    
}

 bool ColorWithinRange(Color c, Color _from, Color _to)//looking for similar colors
       {
    
                return(_from.R <= c.R && c.R <= _to.R) &&
                      (_from.G <= c.G && c.G <= _to.G) &&
                      (_from.B <= c.B && c.B <= _to.B);

       }
```

The problem is that it paints the entire area, and I need this area to be outlined with a line

Now

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqkua.png)

should be
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfo9R.png)

Comment: Could you arrange your code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a color area , the program paints over the entire found area, but I need it to just stroke

Comment: I just want to draw a line around the found color area